# Upload a file to HDFS via php curl

Tags: php, html, hdfs

I am using PHP curl to upload all my files to HDFS. It works fine when I upload up to 60mb file. However, when I try to upload 100mb, it does not upload. Why so?

Below is code I have already tried:

```
$url="http://master:9864/webhdfs/v1/".$name."/".$fname."?op=CREATE&namenoderpcaddress=master:9000&createflag=&createparent=true&overwrite=true";

$file=fopen($filepath, 'r');
$filedata =  fread($file,$size);

$data = array($filedata, $target_file);

echo call_curl($header, $method, $url, $data,$file,$size);
header("Location: ../dashbord/index.php");
```

Comment: I would start by finding out how to get `call_curl()` to show you error messages. Or you could look at the PHP Error log

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
 an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
 then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
 [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/),
 how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: when i press upload, am getting this message: num1/tmp/phpgAt20y

Comment: Did you check if the server side have any kind of "max upload size"??

Comment: i have change the max upload size for php.ini . but still cant upload via rest web service